# Opacity Lines In Window store app

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have problem when draw lines have opacity.
Source i writing:

```
    <Line X1="50" Y1="50" X2="100" Y2="100" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="10" Opacity="0.5" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"/>
        <Line X1="100" Y1="100" X2="150" Y2="100" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="10" Opacity="0.5" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"/>
```

[image]

i would like picture as 
[image]

you can help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you're after, but the basis of what you need to do is essentially to group each line inside one container then reduce the opacity of that container rather than the lines themselves.

For example, if you place the Line's inside a Canvas like so:

```
<Canvas Opacity="0.5">
     <Line X1="50" Y1="50" X2="100" Y2="100" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="10" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"/>
     <Line X1="100" Y1="100" X2="150" Y2="100" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="10" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"/>
</Canvas>
```

You can achieve what you're after:

[image: Grouped Lines]

The Canvas is a great tool for dealing with such things, but if really needed it can be substituted with just about any container that can deal with multiple children (such as a grid).
The key is to make the container control the opacity, not the children themselves.

Comment: thanks you! at the moment, i using polyline resolve problem